# New arraylist created automatically when fragment is put into view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm creating an app where the user can view their score histories and it works fine except that whenever I click on the fragment directly a new arraylist list is automatically created with the previous custom items. When I use the savebutton intent to get to the fragment no such issues arise and the recyclerview is updated as I want it to.

This is how I save scores using a navigation Menu item

```
case R.id.save_game:
            Intent save = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScoreActivity.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("EXTRA_DATE", format);
            save.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(save);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
```

I receive the intent in my ScoreFragment

```
 public void saveScore(){

    Intent intent = requireActivity().getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {

        String format = extras.getString("EXTRA_DATE");

        mScoreList.add(new ScoreItem(TeamAName, TeamBName, scoreTeamA, scoreTeamB, format));

        saveData(); //Saves Arraylist to sharedpreferences

    }
}
```

And then I call `saveScore()` in my oncreateView method

My Score Fragment is attached to ScoreActivity like this

```
public class ScoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                new ScoreFragment()).commit();
    }

}
```

}

I've tried putting my `saveScore()` method in `onViewCreated()` as well as `onResume`  and `onSaveInstanceState` but it doesn't change anything.

Changing `replace()` to `add()` in my ScoreActivity also doesn't do anything.

Right after I inflate my rootView I call `loadData()` and I've been trying to call it somewhere else but it causes crahes.

```
 private void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("task list", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ScoreItem>>() {
    }.getType();
    mScoreList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if (mScoreList == null) {
        mScoreList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

How do I go about resolving this issue?

Comment: Do you mean the ``mScoreList.add`` line keeps getting called, so you get the same score added several times? What do you mean by "click on the fragment directly", is there an onClickListener doing something? ``onViewCreated`` can get called a lot (like if you switch back to the app) so if you're calling ``saveScore`` in there it will fetch the Activity's bundle and extras each time, and add another line to the list if any extras are there

Comment: yes mScoreList.add keeps getting called. So when I navigate to the fragment using my navigation drawer, the arraylist automatically creates a new arraylist although I did not call  saveScore() or send any intents.

Answer (score 0):

`getIntent()` always returns the Intent you used to create that Activity - so if you use that menu item to start a new one and add that extra

```
Intent save = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScoreActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("EXTRA_DATE", format);
save.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(save);
```

then that Activity will always return this Intent + Extras bundle when you call `getIntent`. So if your fragment has this in its `onViewCreated`:

```
    Intent intent = requireActivity().getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

and its parent activity was originally created with that Intent+Extras combo, then it will run your adding code

---

Honestly it depends on how your app is set up, so I can only give you ideas of things to look at

- If you have an activity where fragments get swapped, so `ScoreFragment` can get re-added (you mentioned "using the navigation drawer to navigate to the fragment") then `onViewCreated` will run again with that Intent.
- If it's off-screen and the system destroys its views to save memory, when it's recreated it will run `onViewCreated` again with that Intent.
- If you call `startActivity` in different places, but an existing Activity gets reused (say your Activity is launched as [singleTop or singleInstance](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#TaskLaunchModes)) then it will have the Intent+Extras it was originally created with. So if you first create it through that menu item with the extras, and then call `startActivity()` without the extras from somewhere else, if the original activity gets used it will still have that Intent+Extras it was created with. (It'll receive the new intent through`onNewIntent()` but it won't change the value of `getIntent`)
- Also you're not actually checking if the extras Bundle has the `EXTRA_DATE` item, just if it has *some* extras, and then you're adding a new `ScoreItem` with whatever `extras.getString("EXTRA_DATE")` returns (which might be `null``). So if you're launching with other bundles of extras in different situations, you might still get the extra score added

I know that's a lot and it's not a solution but hope it helps! Honestly I'd recommend setting a breakpoint in `saveScore`, debug the app and use the debugger to see what `getIntent` is giving you, and if it looks right.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve the issue but I have no idea what I actually did. I decided to create an easy splash screen for my app and the problem just disappeared. I'm so confused right now and I would like some help in figuring it out so I can correct it in the future.

I created a new Activity called  SplashScreenActivity

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    EasySplashScreen config = new EasySplashScreen(SplashScreenActivity.this)
            .withFullScreen()
            .withTargetActivity(MainActivity.class)
            .withSplashTimeOut(5000)
            .withBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF9800"))
            .withHeaderText("Header")
            .withFooterText("Footer")
            .withBeforeLogoText("Before Logo Text")
            .withAfterLogoText("After Logo Text")
            .withLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);

    config.getHeaderTextView().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    config.getFooterTextView().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    config.getBeforeLogoTextView().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    config.getAfterLogoTextView().setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    View easySplashScreen = config.create();
    setContentView(easySplashScreen);
}
```

}

Then I moved MainActivity's intent-filter to the Splash Screen Activity in my Manifest.xml
file and this is what I think changed things.

```
 <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

I moved it back to the MainActivity a couple of times and I realized the problem came back each time the intent filter was in MainActivity. Now I keep it in `.SplashScreenActivity` in the Manifest and I have no such issues. I really need some explanation for this.